# VHDL: Errors in FlipFlop D code

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

I am doing a D flip flop with VHDL
This is the code:

```
LIBRARY STD,WORK;
USE STD.standard.all;
entity FlipFlopD is 
port(
  input, clock :in bit;
  output :out bit
);
end FlipFlopD;

--Architecture of the entity
Architecture FlipFlopDfunc of FlipFlopD is 
begin 
  PROCESS (clock)
  BEGIN
    IF (clock’EVENT AND clock=‘1’) THEN 
      output <= input; 
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
end FlipFlopDfunc;
```

These are errors I get when I try to synthesize it:

```
Line 16. Unexpected symbol read: ?.
Line 16. Unexpected symbol read: ?.
Line 16. parse error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting COMMA or CLOSEPAR
```

The error in line 16 is extrange to me because I don´t see any '?' symbol in this line:

```
IF (clock’EVENT AND clock=‘1’) THEN
```

Does anyone know how to correct it?
Does anyone know what to do with this error `parse error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting COMMA or CLOSEPAR`?

By the way, I am doing my design using ISE 9.2
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you use the correct type of single quote (`'`) signs? If they are like this in your VHDL code I guess they are wrong.

```
IF (clock'EVENT AND clock='1') THEN
```

Answer (score 4):

I cut and pasted your code from above, and as bmk says, the ticks are wrong.

You can also write that line as :-

```
if rising_edge(clock) then
```

But you would than have to use the following library and package.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the correct observation by @bmk and by @George, you should *remove* these lines:

```
LIBRARY STD,WORK;
USE STD.standard.all;
```

The VHDL standard dictates that these lines are already implied in any VHDL file.
Those clauses do not have any effect on your code, but they will identify you as a novice.